# ASP.NET Forms Authentication - not redirecting to any page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I'm in the process of learning ASP.NET and am still fairly new to the programming world.

While learning about `authentication/authorization`, I edited my sample app's web config file to enable forms authentication, and authorization to deny all non-logged in users.  I created a blank Login.aspx form as well, but when I try to execute the app, no pages appear.  IE shows:

> "Page can't be displayed"

even though I'm told it should redirect to my `Login.aspx` file automatically.  Other browsers such as Opera show:

> "This webpage has a redirect loop"

This is what I have so far:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    ...
</system.web>
```

I tried adding the `<forms>` tag in between `<authentication />` with `loginUrl` as `Login.aspx`, but still same error.  I've also added the `<location>` tags to allow access to the App_Themes and Images folders.

I'm currently using VS Express 2013 for Web with IIS Express integrated.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The "Page can't be displayed" message started to show after you configure your app to requires authentication? Maybe you are running in some other problem.

Comment: Yes Oberdan.  I'm not sure what the problem is yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this helps anyone out there, I finally found the solution to be that, when implementing the `<forms>` tag, the `loginUrl` attribute should have a value of just the NAME of the login form, WITHOUT the `.aspx` extension.  So it looks like this:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Login" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Thanks to whoever that tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

Enable Anonymous Authentication in the IIS and then try.

Run->ingetmgr->IIS Group->Authentication->RightClick on Anonymous Authenticaion and Enable.

Comment: It seems you have not enabled IIS. try to enable iis feature. would be helpfull in future too.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725762.aspx

Comment: I typed ingetmgr in the Run command but no results?  Just so you know, in the Properties window for my project, under "Developer Web Server", Anonymous Authentication is Enabled.

Comment: How do I enable IIS?  I thought IIS is enabled since my apps were executing fine before authentication.

Comment: I installed IIS 7.5, but I still can't find ingetmgr in the Run command.  Do I have to configure something somewhere?

Comment: Just a machine restart required after enabling IIS. Nothing more than that as far i know :-)

Comment: Hey TomCat, I restarted my comp but still can't find ingetmgr.  However, I opened IIS Manager and under Authentication for IIS, Anonymous Authentication shows status Enabled.  My app still won't execute any pages though.